# MySQL String to Time Format

Tags: mysql

Could you please help.

In the database time represent in string format like 5.5 (hours) how to convert to 5:30 min

I tried

```
select CAST('5.50' AS DATETIME)

select STR_TO_DATE('5.50', '%h:%i %p') ;
```

but this is not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a neat way to do this but here is a hacky way off the top of my head.

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(5.5 * 3600)
```

I'm converting 5.5 into seconds then from seconds to a time.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can add the 5.5 hours interval to time 00:00:00 to get a time of 05:30:00.

This however:

```
select time '00:00:00' + interval '5.5' hour
```

does not work. MySQL truncates the 5.5 to 5 for some reason. So use

```
select time '00:00:00' + interval '5.5' * 60 * 60 second
```

instead.

UPDATE: Just looked it up. That `interval 5.5 hour` does not work was filed as a bug in 2007 here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31013.

Answer (score 0):

To get the time in format `hh:mm:ss` you could use this query.

```
SELECT SUBTIME(TIME(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(0),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 5.5*60 MINUTE)), TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(0)));
```

check it out on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1f8d7/35)

**EDIT**

In case you want `seconds` accuracy then change the query like this.

```
SELECT SUBTIME(TIME(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(0),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 5.501*3600 SECOND)), TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(0)));
```

Comment: Thank you what about if time more then 24 hours?